# Altium Designer: How to tell the auto router not to place vias too close to other components?

Tags: altium

My team is designing a very large PCB in Altium Designer (about four hundred 0603 components) and are using the auto router. The issue we're facing is that the auto router is placing some vias too close to other components (surface mount components, headers, etc.). Is there a way to configure the auto router not to set vias too close to other components?

Comment: Define "too close". Are the copper clearance design rules being violated?

Comment: What rules have you tried? There are almost an infinite variety that can be formulated. The autorouter isn't that great anyway.

Comment: If you can't find a better way, add a layer to the stack, and edit the 0603 component to have a big copper pad on that layer. Naturally, turn that layer OFF when manufacturing the board!

Comment: Minimum solder mask rules are being violated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone to Design-->Rules and set Design Rules-->Electrical-->Clearance-->Clearance? There is a chart there that allows you to tell it how much space you need between different items, whether they be tracks and vias, tracks and components, vias and components, etc. It looks like this:

[image: Clearance settings]

EDIT: Oops, accidentally drew the box around the track column instead of the SMD pad column, but you get the picture ;)

I am pretty sure these are the rules that the Auto-router looks at. I am fairly new to Altium, however, so I could be wrong. Worth checking, anyway. Good luck!

Comment: The router obeys all Electrical and Routing design rules, except the Routing Corners rule.